# ASP.NET CORE model with a collection<string>

Tags: asp.net-core

Hi I'm trying to add to a model the property of colors
color is an array of strings.

**model**

```
public class dog
{
    // other properties
    public ICollection<string> Colors { get; set; }
}
```

**dbContext**

```
public DataContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
{

}
public DbSet<Dog> Dogs { get; set; }
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    builder.Entity<AppUser>().HasMany(user => user.Dogs).WithOne(dog=> dog.AppUser)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

}
```

What relation should I do if I want that if I delete a dog so the colors will be deleted as well? because I'm unable to run the migration because I'm getting this error:

The property 'dogs.Colors' could not be mapped because it is of type 'Collection', which is not a supported
primitive type or a valid entity type. Either explicitly map this property, or ignore it using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'

I tried searching this question but I didn't really find any useful answers to my issue.

Can anyone please explain to me what causes it and what should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can not use ICollection in your database Model becasue that doesn't have equivalent type in Database(such as sqlsever , mysql , ...)

actually you should create other table for 'Color' in this way :

```
public class dog
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    // other properties

    public ICollection<Color> Colors { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class Color
{
    public string Value {get; set;}

    public int DogId {get; set}
    public dog Dog{ get; set; }
}
```

also you can add in your DbContext Class :

```
public DbSet<Color> Colors { get; set; }
```

---

Also if you don't want to save ICollection in database, you can ignore it using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'

For example :

```
[NotMapped]
public ICollection<string> Colors { get; set; }
```

Comment: So i cant just create it with list ?
public List<string> SuitColors { get; set; } 
like this ?

Comment: In this question, There is no difference between ICollection and List and you're getting same error again.

Answer (score 2):

I'm thinking of two ways of handling this...

### **1. Using a **[backing field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/backing-field?tabs=data-annotations)****

---

> Backing fields allow EF to read and/or write to a field rather than a
> property. This can be useful when encapsulation in the class is being
> used to restrict the use of and/or enhance the semantics around access
> to the data by application code, but the value should be read from
> and/or written to the database without using those
> restrictions/enhancement

```cs
public class Dog
{
    // other properties
    private string _colors; //this is the backing field

    public ICollection<string> Colors
    {
        get
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_colors))
                return new List<string>(); //empty list
            return _colors.Split(",");
        }
        set
        {
            //you can have other logic, instead of setting it directly
            //in this case, it will overwrite the old value
            _colors = string.Join(",", value);
        }
     }
}
```

On your database *Dogs table*, have a *column name* of *Colors* with nvarchar or varchar datatype.

When you store the color value, which is a list of string values, convert it to a concatenated single string value. Likewise, whenever you want to have the single string value on your code as a collection, use string to array conversion.

### **2. Re-model your Dog entity**

---

This will have you create two more tables on your database. These tables are **Colors** and **DogsColors**. One thing to note here is both Dog and Color have many to many relationships.

Depending on your dotnet core version, you may have to create one or more **entity models**.

If you are using **Dotnet Core 5** or higher, you only need one entity model **Color**. Otherwise, you may have to add the **DogsColor** entity model.

**Dotnet core 5 or higher:**

.net core 5 [many to many](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many) relationships

> Many to many relationships require a collection navigation property on
> both sides. They will be discovered by conventions like other types of
> relationships.

```cs
public class Color {
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Color { get; set;}
   public ICollection<Dog> Dogs {get;set;} //for many to many relationship
}

public class Dog
{
   public ICollection<Color> Colors { get; set; }
}

//dbcontext configuration
builder.Entity<Dog>()
    .HasMany(i => i.Colors)
    .WithMany(i => i.Dogs)
    .UsingEntity<Dictionary<string, object>>(
        "DogColors",
        x => x.HasOne<Color>().WithMany().HasForeignKey("ColorId"),
        x => x.HasOne<Dog>().WithMany().HasForeignKey("DogId"));
```

If you are using **Dotnet core 3** or lower:

```cs
public class Color {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Color { get; set;}
}

public class DogColor {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Dog Dog { get; set;}
    public Color Color { get; set;}
}

public class Dog
{
   public ICollection<DogColor> DogColors { get; set; }
}
```